# Direct update not working when dynamically changing server url during runtime- MobileFirst 7.1

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I have implemented dynamically changing server URL at runtime. I followed the instruction given in this [link](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2015/02/02/changing-server-url-runtime/). The results were good I was able to connect different servers basically development servers like MFP Server in eclipse. But direct update does not work when a new server is connected. Similarly, if I try the same thing with stand-alone servers like our QA or UAT, then direct update works.

How can I make the direct update work for development servers?

Comment: Direct update needs you to make a change to the wlapp. Was that done with the dev server you pointed to?

Comment: Yes, I made a couple of changes and tried. Other developer machines have the different code but the same version that was the best scenario for the direct update but didn't work.

Comment: If you directly point to this new server( without chaning the url using API), and then make changes to the wlapp , does it trigger direct update?

Comment: @Vivin I tried it does not work. Sounds like the direct update is not enabled in development mode. How can I enable that?

Comment: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/application-development/direct-update/